# leave inner circle white in sunburst diagram

Tags: python, plotly, sunburst-diagram

On the web I can find many sunburst diagrams where the inner circle is left white which looks better for scientific purposes. But I can't find a way to implement this without a workaround to manipulate the data frame. So my goal is to leave the root node white. Level1 in my example code should be visualized in the second node.

```
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['Level1', 'Level2', 'Level3'], values='amount', color='average')
```

Is there a parameter I am missing?

Comment: Have you read the doc ? Do you get any error ? What about writing a [mcve]?

Comment: Yeah, I read the doc (https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.sunburst.html) But I cannot find a parameter that the root node stays white and the plot "begins in the second node". The results is that the plot goes bigger and is more meaningfull. There is no error

Comment: @liambeck Please include a screenshot of what you'd like your figure to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- this is manipulating dataframe, but in transient way
- it is simple and transparent

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.sunburst(df.assign(hole=" "), path=['hole','time', 'sex'], values='total_bill')

fig
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this answer. Yes, it is manipulating the df but in a very nice way.